# How do I force users to access my Play application through SSL?

Tags: ssl, nginx, playframework-2.0

I have a Play application that I've deployed by running `stage` within SBT, and then running it from the command line using `target/start`. I've placed Nginx in front of it and, based on a sub-domain, I have two `server` blocks--one for port 80, and the other for port 443. The port 80 block just redirects to the `https` scheme on port 443. This all works great.

To recap:

- `http://play.mydomain.com/` redirects to
- `https://play.mydomain.com/` which is a proxy for `http://localhost:9000`

However, if I just go to `http://mydomain.com:9000/`, I get access to my Play application directly. There's no SSL, and there's no way I can figure out to keep anyone from accessing it.

What should I do? Should I use Nginx to redirect any access on port 9000 to the URL for the SSL version? Should I firewall port 9000 and only allow local requests on that port? (If so, how would I do that?) Is there some other way of dealing with this that I'm not thinking of?

And how long until the Servlet 3.1 spec is released and I can just deploy the whole thing as a WAR? :-)

Comment: OK. Just discovered I can't have Nginx redirect requests to port 9000 to the right subdomain, because my Play application has already bound itself to port 9000. It's weird that I can't find anything about this on the internet. I'm starting to think I've missed something basic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make your Play application listen only on the local interface (127.0.0.1, for example). That way, nginx can still proxy requests to it but nobody from the outside can access your application directly. No additional firewall setup is necessary.

Looks like you can pass an additional argument to `start`:

`$ start -Dhttp.port=9000 -Dhttp.address=127.0.0.1`

Comment: And the way you do that, apparently, is to use the option `-Dhttp.address=localhost` when you start the application. If you've used `stage` to get the application ready to run, you'd do `target/start -Dhttp.address=localhost` and I've verified that allows access to the application through Nginx, but not by going to port 9000 directly. Thanks!